# "Modernized" OAUTH, WebView no more, impact?

Tags: google-oauth

This is in reference to:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

which asks to post questions on stack overflow under #google-oauth.

Two questions from the developer of an email app for Android.

There are users who have more than one Gmail account, and they don't want to have to add all of them into system Settings.

For accounts which are present in system Settings, I use Google Play Services, it works almost every time, so that's not the scenario I'm discussing.

For accounts not present there, I currently use a WebView to open https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth and it just goes from there.

## 1:

Can someone please clarify what "new OAuth clients" means here?

New installs of existing apps (using WebView)?

Or brand new apps?

What are those "user facing notices" going to look like?﻿

## 2:

What about Android devices that don't have Chrome installed?

Not all do, and I believe it needs Android 4.1 whereas my app runs on 4.0.3+.

Does this mean the owners of these devices are now going to be out of luck?

Comment: Google said they were "monitoring" this tag and we have the same questions.  Can we get an update Google?